# dummy variable based on string

Tags: sas, proc-sql

I want to search through a character variable, find all of the observations that have the word "internet" and insert a 1 into the dummy variable created for those observations.  Really I just need help searching one column for a string, but I cant find a function that I can reference a single column to.

Comment: Did you look very hard at the [documentation](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/allprodslang/63337/HTML/default/viewer.htm#titlepage.htm)?  Perhaps the `INDEX` or `FIND` functions?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
indicator_var = index(variable, "string")
```